# How to test a grep -A 1 variable with a condition (syntaxe issue) - Shell Script

Tags: bash, grep, conditional-statements

Hello i am very new in the programmation and i try to learn by myself shell script.

I have to put a condition on a number after a word (Tetrahedra) i know in a file test.txt ; i have written this :

```
var=`grep -A 1 Tetrahedra test.txt`
if [ "$var" = "Tetrahedra 0" ]
then
#some action
fi
```

But i have an issue syntaxe since echo $var prompt

EDIT:

Tetrahedra
0

I don t know how to put the right syntaxe on my test (i try Tetrahedra\n0) i think i miss the line break

Or maybe there is an easy way to do what i want ? I have thought about a solution but it s very messy (like editing a new file, testing it and then deleting it)

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking, but, if the issue is that the `echo` output is missing line breaks, then use double quotes as in `echo "$var"`

Comment: Don't try to learn shell scripting one script at a time by trial and error as that'll take you a VERY long time, cause you all sorts of unexpected and hard to understand/solve problem, and cause you to have to unlearn many bad habits constantly. Read a decent book on shell, e.g. Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson, and **the** decent awk book, Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins, work through the exercises in both and THEN try to write your own scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a newline using the bash `$'\n'` syntax.  Octal Dump `od -c` is useful for seeing exactly what characters you have, since it can show non-printing characters using escapes.

**test.txt**

```
Tetrahedra
0
Polygon
1
```

**tetra.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

var=`/bin/grep -A 1 Tetrahedra test.txt`
echo -n "$var" | od -c
match="Tetrahedra"$'\n'"0"
echo -n "$match" | od -c
if [ "$var" == "$match" ]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

**Output**

```
bash tetra.sh

0000000   T   e   t   r   a   h   e   d   r   a  \n   0
0000014
0000000   T   e   t   r   a   h   e   d   r   a  \n   0
0000014
YES
```

Comment: ++ for using `od -c` for debugging! Good luck to all.